# Detecting and punishing the downvoters

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

I see that there are strategies that pass the reputation-restore filtering. For instance, my

[image]

reputation was not restored.

Now, during last day I got more downvotes for various posts

[image]

Though they are more diffused in time, I think that it is extraordinary to receive even two downvotes per day for old posts, since are they are of interest to nobody. I have got 8.

Is it just a new strategy conspired by good users to push undesired users away from the site? I feel that this is a punishment for refusing to buy the empty talks as arguments, as I did recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952551/why-dont-we-have-intdelta-a-qustin-about-timedelta/19952607#comment29696114_19952607) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195782/why-does-java-allow-us-to-compile-a-class-with-a-name-different-than-the-file-na/20195840#comment30166395_20195840). Silly people just come up with stupid arguments that they cannot defend in the comments and therefore resort to punish the victims by silently bastardizing their activity elsewhere. [Select * from votes at http://data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/150765/186636/downvoter) hides the punisher IDs.

The problem is not that I am downvoted but I am downvoted without reason. Should I care about that? I am waiting (the people who behave like that) to massively downvote this question.

Comment: What makes you assume it is *one and the same person*? And as the serial-voting post says, you can always ask a moderator for clarification in a chat channel or flag a post to have this investigated, if the serial-downvote script did not catch it.

Comment: Be advised that this post reads a bit like a rant, and may attract downvotes. (Not from me. I'm just providing a friendly warning about what often happens here.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters what makes you think that I think that it is *one and the same person*?

Comment: What makes you think that Martijn thinks that you think that ... wait .... what makes me think ... no you .... nevermind.

Comment: @Val: you are implying that the downvote behaviour is improper and that the serial voting script didn't catch this. There is an automatic serial-vote reversal script that'll take care of improper voting, and I thought you were aware of that already. If the script doesn't catch this behaviour, it is *usually* **not** improper voting behaviour (different people downvoting questions for normal reasons). Rarely it can be someone with sock-puppet accounts evading the script.

Comment: By the way, you seem to imply that your downvotes for September 22nd weren't restored? They were the day after. If that's not what you meant to say, please update your post here.

Comment: @michaelb958 I do not understand the problem with rants. People look for resolution in public forums when they have a problem. They complain, they say what they do not like. This is all ranting. Asking people not to rant is the same to ask the not to ask the questions.

Comment: @Val: What, you think there is no *constructive* way to say this? You could have left out the conspiracy theory here, for starters.

Comment: @Val Well, at the very least [rants like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952551/why-dont-we-have-intdelta-a-qustin-about-timedelta/19952607#comment30225785_19952607) are not going to lead to positive attention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The downvotes are on older posts, that itself makes it rather suspicious.

Comment: @MadScientist: I agree the voting pattern does has me thinking. But with only 2 or 3 clustered downvotes, I do think this is separate people. With the general tone of *this* post it could be the OP aggravated multiple people elsewhere.

Comment: @Val: in any case, the serial voting script applies to multiple votes from *one person*, not multiple people downvoting your posts.

Comment: -1 for lying about "not reversed"

Comment: @Bart sorry, I had no idea that recovery is done by separate transactions.

Comment: As for the second wave of downvotes, I'd wait more before concluding the script isn't going to kick in

Comment: @JanDvorak "Lying" means that liar has an intent to deceive. I had no such intent. I was not aware that reversing leaves downvotes intact. I wounder how people who teach me the tactful behaviour and good manners start by implying my bad intent. Ok, I should behave very bad because I do not do the same. I do not call people liars unless they insist on something wrong. Keep downvoting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The automatic reversal of serial voting by the daily script is only the first line of defense. In cases where you suspect that a user is targeting you specifically with votes and is trying to evade the script, just flag one of your posts for moderator attention and explain the issue, or use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

A moderator or SE employee can then investigate the situation in detail and remove the votes and/or suspend the user.

Answer (score 10):

Serial downvoting is never appropriate. If that happens to you and doesn't get reversed, as Mad Scientist says, you can contact a moderator via a flag, or contact the team and let them have a look.

But going through your comment history in particular, I can't help noticing a thing or two. A significant number of your comments seem to be on the abrasive side at the very least. Stack Overflow isn't a battlefield. But if you treat it like one, people will pay attention. And that attention might not always be positive.

So besides the serial downvoter getting punished (if there really is one), you might want to reconsider your own attitude. And if certain things get you frustrated, try to respond in a polite and constructive manner. And if you can't, perhaps simply don't respond.

Comment: It is not battlefiled but it does not mean that I should accept everything as answer and close my eyes on the nonsense in the other answers. How can you ensure quality if you deny drawing attention to errors?

Comment: Pointing out errors or flaws to an "audience" that is willing to listen is of course no problem. But telling them to literally "shut up" is not going to do you any favours. You don't have to be quiet, you just have to remain polite. And if I find that they are no willing to listen, I usually decide I have better things to do with my time.

Comment: I am asking the person who has confirmed that he had no point in his "argument" to clean up the filed (so that we could better see the real point made by others).

Comment: @Val there is more than one way to respond to nonsense. Exhibit 1: "Who said jQuery was available? Also, don't use `document.write`. Also, the question is about foo, not bar". Exhibit 2: "My eyes ar bl33ding from that code! Delete it nao! And die a horrible death after you do."

Comment: @Val there are ways to disagree and not be combative.  Whether or not your position is correct, when you become aggressive in replies, the chances of encountering serial downvoters increases significantly.  Would you take that tone if it was a colleague sitting across the table from you?

Comment: @psubsee2003 "Shut up" has appeared after I was downvoted. Everything else I would say openly into the face. I have no shame for correcting people. What I really feel shame of is that opening people's eyes is considered offensive and deserves a punishment in our society.

Comment: @Val There is a difference between having no shame in correcting people and being openly aggressive and confrontational. The latter may carry consequences as it will annoy others.

Comment: @Flyk What do you mean being agressive? I feel that people perceive any my disagreement as "confrontational". But, if I see a problem I tell it directly. I come here for the information and sharing ideas, not to be nice. If you express any ideas here, you should be ready to defend them. You do not have problems if you position is solid and appropriate.

Comment: *"I come here for the information and sharing ideas, not to be nice."* ... those two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Bart Being neutral and concrete should be treated as "aggressive". Actually, I "attack" the people with no arguments, asking for some. The only aggression is coming up (and downvoting) with no point.